# SUMIFS in DAX Calculated Column

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns, sumifs

## SUMIFS in DAX Calculated Column

- I am looking to create a DAX calculated column that will recreate the SUMIFS formula in column F in the table below (built in Excel).
- In the Excel table the Allocation column (column F) is a SUMIFS that gives me the Monthly (Column D) Qty (Column E) as a percentage of the annual qty by Customer Type, Family, and MPF (Columns A, B, C).
- This is the SUMIFS formula from Excel to build Allocation column: =E2/SUMIFS($E$2:$E$25,$A$2:$A$25,A2,$B$2:$B$25,B2,$C$2:$C$25,C2)
- I've looked at other solutions for similar questions and can't find one that is relatable enough for what I'm looking to solve.

| CustomerType | Family | MPF | Date | Qty | Allocation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SHR | Family1 | MPF1 | 1-Jan-22 | 18,668 | 7% |
| SHR | Family1 | MPF1 | 1-Feb-22 | 12,917 | 5% |
| SHR | Family1 | MPF1 | 1-Mar-22 | 20,150 | 8% |
| SHR | Family1 | MPF1 | 1-Apr-22 | 20,447 | 8% |
| SHR | Family1 | MPF1 | 1-May-22 | 26,591 | 10% |
| SHR | Family1 | MPF1 | 1-Jun-22 | 26,482 | 10% |
| SHR | Family1 | MPF1 | 1-Jul-22 | 25,398 | 10% |
| SHR | Family1 | MPF1 | 1-Aug-22 | 26,718 | 10% |
| SHR | Family1 | MPF1 | 1-Sep-22 | 23,275 | 9% |
| SHR | Family1 | MPF1 | 1-Oct-22 | 17,357 | 7% |
| SHR | Family1 | MPF1 | 1-Nov-22 | 22,360 | 9% |
| SHR | Family1 | MPF1 | 1-Dec-22 | 15,438 | 6% |
| SUB | Family2 | MPF2 | 1-Jan-22 | 15,407 | 7% |
| SUB | Family2 | MPF2 | 1-Feb-22 | 14,486 | 6% |
| SUB | Family2 | MPF2 | 1-Mar-22 | 19,888 | 9% |
| SUB | Family2 | MPF2 | 1-Apr-22 | 19,238 | 9% |
| SUB | Family2 | MPF2 | 1-May-22 | 21,765 | 10% |
| SUB | Family2 | MPF2 | 1-Jun-22 | 20,367 | 9% |
| SUB | Family2 | MPF2 | 1-Jul-22 | 18,356 | 8% |
| SUB | Family2 | MPF2 | 1-Aug-22 | 23,161 | 10% |
| SUB | Family2 | MPF2 | 1-Sep-22 | 19,623 | 9% |
| SUB | Family2 | MPF2 | 1-Oct-22 | 17,559 | 8% |
| SUB | Family2 | MPF2 | 1-Nov-22 | 18,330 | 8% |
| SUB | Family2 | MPF2 | 1-Dec-22 | 16,175 | 7% |

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, although I'm open to better solutions! I'm not convinced the numerator variable is as good as it gets. Thanks everyone!

```
QtyAlloc = VAR Numerator = IF(['Table'Qty] > 0, 'Table'[Qty], 0)
VAR Denominator = CALCULATE(
  SUM('Table'[Qty]),
  ALLEXCEPT('Table',
    'Table'[CustomerType],
    'Table'[Family],
    'Table'[MPF]
  )
)
RETURN DIVIDE(Numerator, Denominator)
```